# SOAP request returns EOFException in Web Logic

Tags: java, ssl, soap, https, weblogic

I am testing a SOAP request using Web Logic over HTTPS. I have the required classes created from WSDL (using wsimport). I have enabled SSL debugging, and looks like session is established after the handshaking procedure. But, after then I get an EOFException. The same service runs perfectly in HTTP in another port, and I don't have any issue accessing this.

```
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-8, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 405
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1573
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.EOFException: Response contained no data
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:221)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:204)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:118)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:272)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:153)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194.postEWOOrder(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Client Code

```
// These two classes are WSDL -> java generated class
EWOProviderWSEWOWsdl ewoProvider = new EWOProviderWSEWOWsdl();
EWOWsdlPortType servicePort = ewoProvider.getEWOProviderWSEWOWsdlPort();

BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) servicePort;
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider
            .getRequestContext();

// Target End Point URL is set in the context here
requestContext
        .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                    "https://MY Url where WSDL is deployed");

// Timeouts in milliseconds
requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", "25000");
requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", "15000");

// Credentials are set in over here
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("UserName"));
headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("Password"));
requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "80");
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "myproxy_host");

JAXBElement<EWOOrders> ewoOrders = generateWSRequestObject();

String generatedXml = generateXmlRequestForProgistix(ewoOrders);
System.out.println("XML >> " + generatedXml);

DocTypeRefStatusMessageResponse responseMessage = servicePort
    .postEWOOrder(ewoOrders.getValue());
```

After a long search I found something here, but not sure how this can be done as my code is mostly generated by the wsimport and I am just accessing the service via this. See the link I am talking about,

```
http://deepakmodi2006.blogspot.ca/2011/05/how-to-fix-javaioeofexception-response.html
```

Comment: We added some logs on service side, and it looks like the server is being hit with the same request 5 times automatically by Web Logic. But no the client side we still get only one time EOFException: Response contains no data

Answer (score 0):

We did this from a standalone client to reproduce what was really happening and found that there were internally 5 iterations of trial requests sent towards by due to the exception returned from our PROXY.

5 warning / exceptions as mentioned below:

<18 Dec, 2015 9:18:30 AM EST>     secure-test.myserver.com was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure. Check the certificate chain to determine if it should be trusted or not. If it should be trusted, then update the client trusted CA configuration to trust the CA certificate that signed the peer certificate chain. If you are connecting to a WLS server that is using demo certificates (the default WLS server behavior), and you want this client to trust demo certificates, then specify -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust on the command line for this client.>

Finally there will be only one exception thrown by the Client application which is an EOF Exception.

The reason was our proxy was not trusting this communication. After the security team installed the server certificate in it's proxy/certificate store this problem is resolved.